# paramiko-expect change password

Tags: python-3.x, expect, paramiko, openwrt

I have several routers running OpenWRT and I'd like to configure them with a python script using paramiko. Since the 'passwd' command on Linux requires a user input I'm using paramiko-expect to handle the interaction. Changing the password on the host itself looks like the following:

```
root@host1:~# passwd
Changing password for root
New password: new_password 
Retype password: new_password
passwd: password for root changed by root
```

My python script looks like this

```
import paramiko
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction

try:
    with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect('192.168.1.1', 22, 'root', 'old_password')
        
        with SSHClientInteraction(ssh, timeout=10, display=True) as interact:
            interact.expect('.*root.*') # expecting root@host1:~
            interact.send('passwd')
            interact.expect(['.*password.*', '.*password.*']) # expect multiline output both containing the phrase 'password'
            interact.send('new_password')
            interact.expect('.*password.*') # expect 'Retype password: '
            interact.send('new_password')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The script runs with no errors but I can still login with 'old_password', so the password is not changed. Output on my local terminal looks like:

```
BusyBox v1.30.1 () built-in shell (ash)

Welcome to OpenWRT

root@host1:~# passwd
Changing password for root
New password:
Retype password:
```

I've tried a simple

```
interact.send('ls>test')
```

The interesting thing is, the file test is created but it has no content (contains several files when executed on host1 itself). The same happens with

```
interact.send('ip a>test')
```

Interestingly a pwd>test works fine and the current directory is added to the test file. Anybody has an idea what the problem is or how I can debug properly?

paramiko 2.7.2
paramiko-expect 0.3.0
Python 3.8.5
terminal I use to execute the python script: platformio-ide-terminal addon for atom 2.10.1

Regards Ian

Comment: Are you reading the error output?

Comment: could you try adding `interact.expect('password for root changed by root')` after the second `interact.send('new_password')`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No I am not, how would I do that?

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells I don't now why but that worked just fine, on the password task as well as the 'ip a'. Thank you. I figured the command should have been executed by that time, so what does the additional expect change?

Comment: without the added `expect()` your script would exit immediately after sending the second passwd and the ssh connection would be broken and the passwd command does not have enough time to finish.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells: That makes sense thank you. Can I mark your comment as accepted answer?

Comment: it's ok to keep it as a comment. :)